# Url outside the loop

Tags: loop

How to get the url of thumbnail and single page link outside the loop. For thumbnail, I tried

```
    wp_get_attachment_url();
```

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste below code. you can replace 'get_the_ID()' with page/post id otherwise it will return image for current page/post.  cheers!!!

```
$size = "full";
$urlarr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),   $size);

$imgurl = $urlarr[0];
```

this will return complete url of the image.